# Fatal error in wp-admin/customize.php after fresh install due to null $wp_customize

Tags: customization, errors, theme-customizer, fatal-error

I get the following error when clicking on `Customize Your Site` after a clean install. It appears that `$wp_customize` is incorrectly null in the specified file? The entire install is successful, and I'm having a hard time finding documentation on the issue.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function changeset_post_id() on null in /home/<user>/blog/wp-admin/customize.php:29 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/<user>/blog/wp-admin/customize.php on line 29
```

Comment: Try re-uploading the files for the WP installation.

Comment: possibly a theme error also, if the `$wp_customize` global is not handled correctly there, maybe try reinstalling theme also

Comment: @DaveRomsey it's the default WordPress theme. Even after a reinstall the problem is still present. I've even installed a custom theme, and the problem is still present after installation.

Comment: @majick see above :)

Comment: Are you using any plugins or mu-plugins? `$wp_customize` is set in `_wp_customize_include()` which is hooked to `plugins_loaded`. That function breaks early when `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` doesn't equal to `customize.php`. Can you try accessing `/wp-admin/customize.php?wp_customize=on`? If that *does* work, it appears to be a server configuration issue.

Comment: @swissspidy accessing that URL does indeed work. What could be wrong with a server configuration in this case? nginx server config? permissions? I do not have any plugins enabled, only the defaults are installed but inactive.

Comment: It would be the nginx configuration then. If you google for `PHP_SELF` and nginx, you'll find results like http://kbeezie.com/php-self-path-nginx/ and https://serverfault.com/questions/626552/php-fpm-nginx-giving-scripts-wrong-path-info that would give you a hint for debugging why `PHP_SELF` isn't set properly on your server. If it's not your self-hosted server, you might want to reach out to your hosting company.

Comment: @swissspidy Thanks for your help! I got the nginx config fixed, there was clearly an issue with the instructions I followed for setting up nginx within a subdirectory of another app.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I got some faulty `nginx` configuration from an article on how to configure WordPress in a subdirectory.

**Config Before**

```
location @wp {
    rewrite ^/blog(.*) /blog/index.php?q=$1;
}

location ^~ /blog {
    root /home/user;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @wp;

    location ~ \.php$ {

        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        # Deleted this line
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/blog)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    }
    break;
}
```

**Config After**

```
location @wp {
    rewrite ^/blog(.*) /blog/index.php?q=$1;
}

location ^~ /blog {
    root /home/user;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @wp;

    location ~ \.php$ {

        include fastcgi_params;

        # Added this line
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    }
    break;
}
```

As mentioned in some comments, some PHP Server variables were incorrectly set due to a faulty nginx configuration causing issues when loading `/wp-admin/customize.php`

You can confirm your nginx configuration is faulty for this scenario if you visit `/wp-admin/customize.php?wp_customize=on` and it starts to work instead of throwing a fatal error.